# New mails are delivered in /mail not in /mail/new

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot, squirrelmail

I have Postfix, Dovecot and SquirrelMail installed on my server. I want all mails to be sent to `/var/mail/$USER/new` (because SquirrelMail is looking into `/new` folder for new mails). But after hours of configuring, my mails are delivered into `/var/mail/$USER/` thus SquirrelMail can't find it.

Postfix main.cf:

```
home_mailbox = mail/
```

Dovecot 10-mail.conf:

```
mail_location=maildir:/var/mail/%u
```

I'm running debian distro.

Comment: What is your actual delivery agent postfix local or dovecot?

Comment: Did you create each users Maildir directory beforehand ? (maildirmake)

Comment: OP here, it was posted in guest mode.. Anyway, how I'll determine what delivery agent is used? It believe it was dovecot or local but I'm not sure. Could you guide me somehow @NickW ? Yes, I created all mail directories for each user that's not the problem. Problem is that mails are delivered into /users directory and not into /user/new folder (more on screen). [User's mail dir. You can see mails (msg files) outside the NEW folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BVqt.png)

Comment: Be glad to help, you'll have a `mailbox_command` or if you're using virtual users, you'll have a `virtual_transport` option (with corresponding master.cf line )